# Display random month from a button click on android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to create an app that lets the user click a button and it will display a random month. I have created a string array in my strings.xml file. Bellow is my main.java, strings.xml and activity.xml. I try to run the app and it just force closes.

```
package com.example.datebutton;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class Main extends Activity
{
Button btn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    final String[] months = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Months);
    final TextView tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 12);
            tv.setText(months[rand]);

        }
    });

}

}
```

here is my activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="updateMonth"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="68dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@array/Months" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here is my strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">DateButton</string>

<string-array name="Months">
    <item>January</item>
    <item>Feburary</item>
    <item>March</item>
    <item>April</item>
    <item>May</item>
    <item>June</item>
    <item>July</item>
    <item>August</item>
    <item>September</item>
    <item>October</item>
    <item>November</item>
    <item>December</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

I'm still getting errors and the app still says unfortunately your app closed. The logcat is below.

09-11 16:55:17.472: W/Resources(1638): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0c0000 a=-1 r=0x7f0c0000}
09-11 16:55:17.512: D/AndroidRuntime(1638): Shutting down VM
09-11 16:55:17.512: W/dalvikvm(1638): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a8fba8)
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638): Process: com.example.datebutton, PID: 1638
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.datebutton/com.example.datebutton.Main}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at com.example.datebutton.Main.onCreate(Main.java:24)
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
09-11 16:55:17.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1638):     ... 11 more

Comment: Stack trace please. Does it crash on start or does it crash after button click ?

Comment: Did you add your Activity to your manifest file.

Comment: it crashes once i start up the app.

Comment: paste your logcat infromation here.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the line: `setContentView(R.layout.activity);` before trying to instantiate your button object btn.

Answer (score 0):

To use layout in you Activity you have to connect them both together. Below is how your code should look like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    final String[] months = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Months);
    final TextView tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int r, g, b;
            int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 12);
            tv.setText(months[rand]);
        }
    });
}
```